# Replace part of HTML string with Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I need to replace part of the HTML tag for displaying YouTube videos:

```
<div class="pretty-embed" data-pe-videoid="IL5AbXBqzwk" data-pe-fitvids="true">&nbsp;</div>
```

with direct link to YouTube image while keeping ID which is defined in data-pe-videoid attribute:

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/YiF7e7m2jPo/sddefault.jpg">
```

If I break it in two parts, I would need to replace

```
<div class="pretty-embed" data-pe-videoid="
```

with

```
<img src="img.youtube.com/vi
```

and

```
" data-pe-fitvids="true">&nbsp;</div>
```

with

```
/sddefault.jpg">
```

I'm looking for a solution with PHP or jQuery/vanilla JavaScript. I tried to experiment with PHP & regular expression but without success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: I cannot understand whad you want exactly. How `<div>` and `<img>` in your question are related?

Comment: do you want to replace the `div` itself or want to add the `img` to the `div`

Comment: Sorry if wasn't clear enough. I've added extra description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using jQuery to add/append an image to each div since its not clear what you mean by "replace part of html":

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('[data-pe-videoid]').each(function() {
      var el = $(this);

      // append img

      el.append($('<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + el.data('pe-videoid') + '/sddefault.jpg">'));
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Alternatively replace instead of append:

```
el.replaceWith($('<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + el.data('pe-videoid') + '/sddefault.jpg">'));
```

Comment: Alex, your solution with replaceWith is what I was looking for.

Comment: could you please post pure javascript equivalent?

I got this far: https://jsfiddle.net/esedic/27acqb8r/